# The annotation @Qualifier is disallowed for this location

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, qualifiers

```
@Override
@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier("hibernateCriteriaBuilder")
public void setCriteriaBuilder(IQueryCriteriaBuilder<Entity> criteriabuilder)
{
  super.setCriteriaBuilder(criteriaBuilder):
}
```

This in the code I have in a java file and i keep getting a error saying: "The annotation @qualifier is diallowed for this location." Can someone explain to me how I can fix this error? I have it twice in my code and have had trouble finding a solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe you'll have more luck using it on the parameter of your method, like so:

```
@Override
@Autowired
public void setCriteriaBuilder(
    @Qualifier("hibernateCriteriaBuilder") IQueryCriteriaBuilder<Entity> criteriabuilder)
{
    super.setCriteriaBuilder(criteriaBuilder):
}
```

You cannot use `@Qualifier` on a method, because what if you wanted to autowire *two* beans instead of just one -- how would it know which one is which?